# UITable View cellForRowAtIndexPath: How to return no cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to delete a cell from the table from the table view when no data is returned from Parse. But no matter what I try I can't find any solution to keep from having a blank cell (Cell when no data is passed) ahead of the cell with content.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    NSString *identifier;
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        identifier = @"Cell";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        identifier = @"Cell2";
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];


    }

// Configure the cell

if (![@"test"  isEqual: [object objectForKey:@"teacher"]]){

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    nameLabel.text = @"";

    UILabel *prepTimeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    prepTimeLabel.text = @"";


return cell;

} else {

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"message"];

    UILabel *prepTimeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    prepTimeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"teacher"];

    return cell;

}
}
```

Thanks for any help given!

Comment: When you delete a cell the row number for that cell is not still reserved for that cell.  Rather, it's assigned to the next cell in the cell order (and the number of cells in the section is reduced by one).  Ie, there's nothing to not return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control the number of cells in a `UITableView` from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method - You need to return the correct value from the `numberOfRowsInSection` method.  Refer to the [UITableViewDataSource protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

Addtionally, this code block -

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    identifier = @"Cell";
} else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    identifier = @"Cell2";
}
```

is somewhat redundant - all of your cells are `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, so they are interchangeable.  Using two different identifiers is not necessary - If you intend to use different custom cell types in the future then you can keep this concept, but you probably wouldn't use the indexPath.row directly, rather you would be driven by the data type in your model for the row in question.